# azure-devops Merge Issue for Test Branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, git-merge, pull-request, git-merge-conflict

we have azure devops repo setup with Master > TEST > Development

for last sprint we merged changes from Development to TEST and had merge conflicts 
one of the developer created local TEST branch and Merged Development changes to resolve changes and committed changes using local TEST branch

After that pullrequest is created from local TEST branch to Remote TEST branch & completed pull request

Now if we create pullrequest from Development to remote TEST  it shows  remote TEST is having latest changes

Any help will be appreciated and what all options available to resolve this issue

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Uno.png)

Thank you 
Dyanesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my reproduction of your question. Is the process you want to express as shown below?

First clone the remote repo to the local and merge from the `local Development` branch into the `local Test` branch. Then push the `local Test` branch to the `remote Test` branch.

[image]   [image]

Then when you create a pull request from the `Development` branch to the `Test` branch in azure devops, you get the following prompt.

[image]

If so, this is normal, because you have merged the changes from the `development` branch to the `local Test` branch locally, and then pushed the changes from the `local Test` branch to the `remote Test` branch. At this point, the `remote development` branch has been synchronized with the `Test` branch, so naturally there are no changes that need to be merged.

If I misunderstood the issue, please point it out. It would be much easier for people to understand and reply if you could attach screenshots of detailed steps.

Comment: Thank you for reply, just after some research i see
1) We merged remote local branch from remote development few times using pullrequest and completing it.
2) After that used same remote local branch to merge changes to remote development branch 
3) Now even though remote DEV and TEST branch are in sync, when we do pullrequest from DEV to TEST (remote) it shows still some changes are pending.

how to solve this issue any help will help us resolve this.

Comment: The version control you are using is git or tfvc? Can you explain how to create a pull request from a local branch to a remote branch and `remote local branch` refer to what?

Comment: We are using Git with Azure DevOps, we create Pullrequest from https://dev.azure.com/Repo where users are allowed to select source and target branch. remote local branch refers to users remote branch (that is i have created a branch from remotes/origin/development to remotes/User1/DecemberChangesBranch). problem is few times we used https://dev.azure.com/Repo to merge  users remote branch by create pullrequest from remote/origin/development to  remotes/User1/DecemberChangesBranch  and completing the request.  will this cause any issue  ?

Comment: Can you please click Flow in my question to understand workflow of this issue

Comment: According to the flow you provided, after the third pr is completed, the test branch and the development branch have been kept in sync, then the fourth pr from the development branch to the test branch should normally show `There are no changes to merge between the selected branches.` Show `some changes are pending`, there should be someone else who modified the development branch, you can click on pending changes to view the commits record and see which commit caused this situation.

Comment: Thank you very much Hugh for above details, followed your steps in your answer & issue is fixed. but trying to understand why merging with pull request is causing issue ? is this something happens often when using pull request for merging ?

Comment: Normally using pull requests for merging does not cause this issue. If this answer is helpful to you ,you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply, just after some research i see
1) We merged remote local branch from remote development few times using pullrequest and completing it.
2) After that used same remote local branch to merge changes to remote development branch 
3) Now even though remote DEV and TEST branch are in sync, when we do pullrequest from DEV to TEST (remote) it shows still some changes are pending.

how to solve this issue any help will help us resolve this. flow explained in this diagram

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EDyT.png)